# Does a large value in uiscrollview's content size affect the allocations in the device memory?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

Suppose I have used the following code in my objective c iphone programming,

```
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(51200, 400)];
```

where 51200 is supposed to be a large valued width for the scrollview and 400 its height.

Would this statement increase the allocations in an iphone device? Or would that cause any other related problems getting it to run on the device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning a larger size won't increase allocations itself. However, putting lots of content inside that scrollview will.

What you should do is check the contentOffset of the scrollview and add/remove content (scrollview subviews) based upon what is actually visible in the scrollview (perhaps inside scrollViewDidScroll).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Is there any way I can confirm this? Can I know for sure using Instruments or any similar application softwares.

Comment: Well when you create a scrollView object it is still one object even if it's a different size. It doesn't take up more memory just because it has a larger content size. You can test this by creating an app with a simple scrollview on it and running it under the allocations tool. Then change the content size and run it again. Size will be same. A scrollView object is not an object like a video file which can have a varying file size.

Comment: Thanks ade. That helped a lot.